# Creating loop for Lines data (spatial data)?

Tags: r, loop, list

I am trying to build a lines shapefile with the contour lines from the 20 meters isobath from along the East African coast.

This contour line of 20 meters has different segments and I have this information on a list, and I am trying to convert this list into a shapefile and merging the different segments of the line.

How could I create a loop to join the different lines of the contour line?

```
library(maptools)
library(sp)

# ctlns: contour lines
ctlns
[[1]]
[[1]]$level
[1] -20
[[1]]$x
[1] 39.11667 39.10909 39.11667 39.12754 39.11667
[[1]]$y
[1] -5.327083 -5.316667 -5.303509 -5.316667 -5.327083

[[2]]
[[2]]$level
[1] -20
[[2]]$x
 [1] 39.21667 39.20889 39.21667 39.21852 39.22667 39.23068 39.23333 39.24369 39.25000
[10] 39.25311 39.25173 39.25202 39.25000 39.23763 39.23333 39.22281 39.21667
[[2]]$y
 [1] -5.053763 -5.050000 -5.035417 -5.033333 -5.016667 -5.000000 -4.998276 -4.983333
 [9] -4.977907 -4.983333 -5.000000 -5.016667 -5.022381 -5.033333 -5.040000 -5.050000
[17] -5.053763

for(i in 1:length(ctlns))
{
  ctlns[[i]]
  isolines<- data.frame(ctlns[[i]])  
  iso <- cbind(isolines$x,isolines$y)
  L1 <-Line(iso)
  Ls1 = Lines(list(L1), ID = "a")
  iso_spatial<-mapply(cbind, list(L1))
}
```

I am new using spatial data on R.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 iso_spatial <- ContourLines2SLDF(ctlns)
```

See the source of `?ContourLines2SLDF` to see how it's done, and how you might restructure (if needed).

Also see `?rasterToContour` in the raster package for a more convenient wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

What is the class of the elements in ctlns? If they are SpatialLines you can use do.call, with rbind, to combine them into a single sp `SpatialLines` object. eg., `do.call("rbind", ctlns)`

However, I am assuming that this is the result of a specific function and a specific class object where "level" is the contour interval and x, y are vertices coordinates. You could loop through this data structure using `lapply` and build a list of `SpatialLinesDataFrame` (see `?SpatialLines` and ?SpatialLinesDataFrame) objects and then use `do.call`, in the same way, to combine the contour lines. In this way you can maintain the contour interval as a column. This is likely what the maptools `ContourLines2SLDF` function that @mdsumner mentions does.